# Exclusion Condition for SQL MS Access Query

Tags: sql, vb.net, vba, ms-access

Requirement: Generate a query that outputs data based on phone numbers in response to user inputs being StartDate, EndDate and Upper Data Threshold.

These input variables are bounds for the query. As such, the SELECT statement was written below accordingly.

The only caveat is that if a phone number has a single record that exceeds the Upper Data Threshold, then ALL phone number records associated to that violating phone number should not be outputted regardless of other records of that same phone number that don't violate the data threshold. Below is sample input and expected output:

```
User input Start Date: 1/15/2015
User input End Date: 11/15/2015
User input Upper Data Threshold in kB: 50

[Master] Table in Access:
Invc Date  Mobile Nbr     PktDtVol   
---------  ----------     --------   
1/15/15   647-409-8206    48kB
2/15/15   647-409-8206    33kB
3/15/15   647-409-8206    8000kB
4/15/15   647-409-8206    20kB
5/15/15   647-409-8206    10kB
6/15/15   647-409-8206    0kB
7/15/15   718-500-2311    3kB
8/15/15   718-500-2311    45kB
9/15/15   718-500-2311    25kB
10/15/15  514-300-3311    33kB
11/15/15  514-300-3311    20kB
```

Expected Output in [Temp_Table]:

```
Invc Date  Mobile Nbr     PktDtVol    Difference in Days 
---------  ----------     --------   -------------------
7/15/15    718-500-2311    3kB             304
8/15/15    718-500-2311    45kB            304
9/15/15    718-500-2311    25kB            304
10/15/15   514-300-3311    33kB            304
11/15/15   514-300-3311    20kB            304
```

My current solution:

```
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime, [Upper Bound
Usage in KB] IEEEDouble;

SELECT [Master].[Invc Date], [Master].PktDtVol, [Master].[Mobile Nbr],
DateDiff("d",[Start Date],[End Date]) AS [Difference in days] INTO
Temp_Table
FROM [Master]
WHERE ((([Master].[Invc Date]) >= [Start Date] And
       ([Master].[Invc Date])<=[End Date]) AND
      (([Master].PktDtVol)<= [Upper Bound Usage in KB]));
```

The 647-409-8206 record is not expected in the output since it took only 1 record to surpass the 50kB (being the 3rd record), then ALL 647-409-8206 records would be omitted accordingly.

Appreciate any help please! Thanks!

Comment: Those look like real phone numbers and search as real phone numbers. Are you sure you want to share this with quite a few people?

Comment: They're certainly fake numbers, I've modified the data accordingly - but thanks!

Comment: You also appear to have some design errors.

Comment: Look at `NOT IN` and a sub query.

Comment: I've looked into that but cannot apply it to my example here unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write a subquery selecting all (distinct) mobile numbers for which a row violates the threshold. Afterwards select from the table all rows `WHERE [Mobile Nbr] NOT IN (subquery)`.

Comment: Both answers helped! Here's the exact SELECT statement I used:      PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime, [Upper Bound Usage in KB] IEEEDouble;
SELECT m.[Invc Date], m.PktDtVol, m.[Mobile Nbr], DateDiff("d",[Start Date],[End Date]) AS [Difference in days] INTO Temp_Table
FROM Master AS m
WHERE (m.[Invc Date]>=[Start Date] And m.[Invc Date])<=[End Date] AND m.[Mobile Nbr] NOT IN
(SELECT q.[Mobile Nbr]
FROM Master AS q
WHERE (q.PktDtVol>=[Upper Bound Usage in KB]));

Comment: In following up, is there a way to optimize this? I'm dealing with >100,000 records, and the query currently takes very long to complete (close to hanging)

Comment: Depends a bit on your database system - I don't tend to work with ms-access (and if switching is an option I'd recommend Postgres, SQL Server or Oracle, or SQLite for light-weight applications), but I could imagine that MS Access handles subqueries poorly. So you could try a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with the subquery, adding a `WHERE` clause in which you ensure that the subquery key `IS NULL'. Basically `SELECT ... FROM table LEFT OUTER JOIN (subquery) s ON ... WHERE s.[Mobile Nr] IS NULL`. This should ensure that the subquery is only evaluated once.

Comment: I'm confused at the `ON ... WHERE s.[Mobile Nr] IS NULL`. What is required between the `ON` and the `WHERE`?

Comment: Simple the join condition by which you join the table with the subquery. In your case that would be `t.[Mobile Nr] = s.[Mobile Nr]` if `t` is your table and `s` your subquery.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've put in the query as mentioned and tested on a few tables. It looks good so far. I'll continue to test. In the meantime (for anyone else), here is the successful query below:

Comment: `PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime, [Upper Bound Usage in KB] IEEEDouble;
SELECT [Master].[Invc Date], [Master].PktDtVol, [Master].[Mobile Nbr], DateDiff("d",[Start Date],[End Date]) AS [Difference in days] INTO Temp_Table
FROM [Master]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT q.[Mobile Nbr]
FROM Master AS q
WHERE (q.PktDtVol>=[Upper Bound Usage in KB])) s
ON [Master].[Mobile Nbr] = s.[Mobile Nbr]
WHERE s.[Mobile Nbr] IS NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

This is quite rough, and your design needs work, but it should give you a start.

```
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DATETIME, [End Date] DATETIME, [Upper Bound Usage in KB]
IEEEDOUBLE;

SELECT m.[invc date],
       m.[mobile nbr],
       m.[pktdtvol],
       Datediff("d", [start date], [end date]) AS [Difference in days]
INTO   temp_table
FROM   master AS m
WHERE  m.[invc date] >= [start date]
       AND m.[invc date] <= [end date]
       AND m.[mobile nbr] NOT IN
           (SELECT q.[mobile nbr]
            FROM   master q
            WHERE  q.pktdtvol >= [upper bound usage in kb])
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working as my recordset is over 60,000 records. I've attempted using INDEXING and so far it hasn't worked. Is there another solution or perhaps INDEXING isn't being used correctly? I created an index using "CREATE INDEX"