# How not to select values which exist in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have two MySQL tables table1 and table 2.

Table 1:-

```
batch    semester  scode
IT         6        DA
IT         6        IA
IT         6        FA
```

Table 2:-

```
batch    subject   user
IT        DA       1
```

I want to run a query to get this output:-

```
scode
IA
FA
```

So basically I want to retrieve values from table 1 which does not exist in table2 for a user with id 1 and where the batch is IT and the semester is 6. I am new to the concepts of fetching data from two tables so I am unable to think of a way to do this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude Certain Records with Certain Values SQL Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983582/exclude-certain-records-with-certain-values-sql-select)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT 
scode
FROM TABLE1 T1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.scode = T2.subject
);
```

---

<kbd>[**SEE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4fac3/1/0)</kbd>

---

You can use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT 
scode
FROM TABLE1 T1 
WHERE T1.scode NOT IN (
   SELECT T2.subject FROM TABLE2 T2 
)
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4fac3/3/0)

---

Comment: I need to select the scode on the basis of the batch and the semester.

Comment: How these two tables are related?

Comment: @KartikeyVishwakarma . . . You changed the question after this answer was posted.  That is rude, because this answer is now out-of-date and someone who went out of their way to help you could get downvotes.  I would suggest that you retract your edits, accept this answer, and ask another question.