# SQL Excluding data based on certain criteria for a date range

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

[How to exclude records with certain values in sql select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389091/how-to-exclude-records-with-certain-values-in-sql-select)

I need to exclude the entire month where Video or Face-to-Face exist but keep the months where either one of those options is not found. I'm using the NOT EXISTS which works but when I filter based on a date range, it excludes everything because it found a single instance somewhere in the date range

| C1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 149000 | 2022-06-21 00:00:00.000 | Telephone |
| 149000 | 2022-06-21 00:00:00.000 | Video |
| 149000 | 2022-06-24 00:00:00.000 | Telephone |
| 149000 | 2022-07-08 00:00:00.000 | Telephone |
| 149000 | 2022-07-15 00:00:00.000 | Telephone |
| 149000 | 2022-07-22 00:00:00.000 | Telephone |
| 149000 | 2022-07-29 00:00:00.000 | Telephone |
| 149000 | 2022-08-12 00:00:00.000 | Telephone |
| 149000 | 2022-08-26 00:00:00.000 | Telephone |
| 149000 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 | Face-to-Face |
| 149000 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 | Face-to-Face |
| 149000 | 2022-09-12 00:00:00.000 | Telephone |
| 149000 | 2022-09-12 00:00:00.000 | Video |

The two commented lines are tests lines to see what it would do to my results.

```
SELECT 
    c1
    ,c2
    ,C3

FROM  a1

WHERE
not exists (SELECT * FROM a1 as B WHERE b.c1 = a1.c1 and (b.c3= 'Face-to-Face' or b.c3 = 'Video') )
--and a1.c2 between '2022-06-01' and '2022-06-30')    
--and a1.c2 = b.c2)

and c2 between '2022-01-01' and '2022-12-30'
```

Comment: `exclude the entire month where Video or Face-to-Face exist` literally uses the word OR. So, if one OR other exists, exclude the month.

Comment: `but keep the months where either one of those options is not found` uses the word EITHER, which effectively means OR. So, KEEP months where either value is missing.

Comment: How do you exclude a month where A OR B is present, yet keep a month where A OR B is missing? Neither present: keep. Both present: excluded. Only A: keep AND exclude. Only B: keep AND exclude.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM a1
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, c2) NOT IN (
    SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, c2) FROM a1 WHERE c3 IN ('Video', 'Face-to-Face')
)
```

Comment: Pleae don't link images of data or results. Include them in the answer as text and use the inbuilt text formatting.

Comment: I don't like your answer. You have a link to an image of data. Which is against SO's best practices, for a litany of reasons. Please read this;  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your help. Helped me get where I needed to with my data.

```
SELECT 
   c1
   ,c2
   ,C3

FROM  a1

WHERE
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, c2), 0) not in (
Select DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, c2), 0) 
from a1 
where c1= a1.c1 and c3 IN ('Video', 'Face-to-Face'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this?

```
select main.* 
from a1 main
where extract(month from main.c2) not in(
    select extract(month from sub.c2)
    from a1 sub
    where sub.c3 in ('Video', 'Face-to-Face')
)
```

Comment: Extract didn't work in SMSS or Cache but it gave me an idea on using MONTH(date-expression). I'll see what happens.